# Init terminating in boot error while starting a rabbitmq (3.7.3) server on CentOS 7 using rabbitfixture

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed `RabbitMQ 3.7.3` and `Erlang/OTP 20.0` and running my unittests against it using `rabbitfixture` but when `rabbitfixture` starting RabbitMQ server it giving me the below error.

`"init terminating in di_boot", {undef, [{rabbit_nodes_common,make,["tmppIN_su@localhost"].[]},{rabbit_prelaunch,start,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_prelaunch.erl"},{line,41}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}`

Pardon me for less information but that is all I got in the log file.  Is there something I can change or fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the line of code raising the error: [link](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.3/src/rabbit_prelaunch.erl#L41).

Notice that it is trying to call `rabbit_nodes:make/1` but your output indicates a call to `rabbit_nodes_common:make/1`. This means that you have upgraded from a previous version of RabbitMQ and there is an old code file around, or there is some other odd issue in your environment.

I recommend starting from a fresh VM or at least removing RabbitMQ and ensuring that all installed files are removed before re-installing.

Be sure to remove `/usr/lib/rabbitmq` after un-installation, for instance.